# How can I insert join then update a flag reflecting update

Tags: mysql

Good afternoon everyone.
I am using MySQL, and I'm looking to take a row from table 1 and either UPDATE or INSERT into table 2.  I have that logic down.  However, after I do either update or insert into table 2 I'm looking to delete the row from table 1.  We don't have the merge option in MySQL as far as I know.  This does not work on a loop from anywhere else, and my thought was to mark a flag column in table 1 as it does each row.  So the

`UPDATE can say SET t2.x = t1.x, t2.y=t1.y,t2.flag=1...`

then I can

`DELETE FROM t1 WHERE flag = 1.`

However, how do I update the row in t1 that is "inserted" (instead of updated) into t2?

Comment: If the suggestion is a trigger, how do I limit that trigger to only run from this insert?  In other words, I don't want it to run whenver there is an insert to Table 2 from any other source.

Comment: Create BEFORE DELETE trigger on table 1 which performs INSERT .. ODKU on table 2. And you delete the row - this causes needed insert or update.

Comment: That was right in front of me, but I didn't see it.  Thank you Akina.  That makes so much sense.